# Function composition early return

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, composition

I am composing a series of function but I wonder what's the best way to achieve what I want first this is how I compose:

```
const composeP = (...fns) => fns.reduce((f, g) => async (...args) => f(await g(...args)))

const profileSummary = profileData => composeP(createProfileSummary, getMKAProfile)(profileData)
```

now what I want is to do a check and if profileData which is my input is a certain string e.g. "cantbesearched" I want to return a value immediately to "profileSummary" variable instead of executing previous functions...

so is it possible to create a "filterWords" function, put it in front of the composition like this:

```
const profileSummary = profileData => composeP(createProfileSummary, getMKAProfile, filterWords)(profileData)
```

and if certain words are detected, skip previous functions on the left then return a value.

Comment: It will probably require passing a more complex value as the accumulator argument to the reduction function. This can contain a flag saying whether the terminating value has been found, and if this flag is set it should just return the accumulator without updating it.

Comment: It will definitely be more complicated and confusing than just using a traditional loop.

Comment: @Barmar That's the first thought came to my mind but I wondered if someone knows something else.

Comment: Another possibility is to set a variable in the shared scope of all the callback functions.

Comment: @Barmar True, reasonable thanks.

Comment: You might want to look into a `transducer` if you want to stick with FP ideas. This should let you `bail early`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to create a "filterWords" function to be put it in front of the composition?

No. What you want to do is branching, which is not possible with function composition.

What you can do is compose functions that work on a type which provides an error path, like `Maybe` or `Either`. (You can also consider exceptions as a builtin error path for every type, so just `throw`).
Oh wait, you already are doing that! You didn't write a plain function composition `compose`, you wrote `composeP` which uses monadic Kleisli composition - and promises *do* have such an error path:

```
function filterWords(word) {
    return word == "cantbesearched"
      ? Promise.reject(new Error("filtered for your safety"))
      : Promise.resolve(word);
}
```

Comment: Beautiful. You really know your stuff.